# using a String to call a function of a class?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a periodic table program in java. the code is pretty huge so I am not putting the whole thing here. this is the class I am using to store and print the values of each element:-

```
class elements
{
    int atomicno;
    String name;
    double weight;

    void setdetails(int a, String n, double w)                                        
    {
        atomicno=a;
        name=n;
        weight=w;
    }

    void showdetails()
    {
        System.out.println("Atomic no.=" +atomicno);
        System.out.println("Name=" +name);
        System.out.println("Weight=" +weight);
    }
}
```

In the main class I made 118 objects of this class and hard-coded info of each element using `setdetails()` like this:

```
elements H=new elements();
H.setdetails(1, "Hydrogen", 1.008);
```

now I am asking the user to enter an element symbol like H, He, Li, etc to search for its info but I think you have to use an actual `object` to call the `showdetails()` function like `H.showdetails()` but i still tried with the `String` entered by the user like this:

```
System.out.print("Enter the correct exact symbol to search:");
String sym=sc2.nextLine();

for(i=0; i<118; i++)
{
    if(s[i].equals(sym))
    {
        System.out.println();
        sym.showdetails();                                    
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and undoubtedly `sym.showdetails();` doesn't work even if the name of the object and the symbol entered by the user is same. so now if I do `H.showdetails();` it works but `sym.showdetails();` doesn't work even if `sym` is `H`. what can be done now?

Comment: You are looking for a `Map<Element>` data structure, implemented as a `HashMap<Element>`

Comment: Don't define 118 variables.  Use a `Map`.

Comment: i am new i don't know anything about maps :/

Comment: s[i].showdetails(); is what you are looking for. You matched the user input String with a field of an object. You need to invoke the method on that particular object.

Comment: why not using `s[i].showdetails()` directly?

Comment: ptable.java:379: error: cannot find symbol
                                s[i].showdetails();
                                    ^
  symbol:   method showdetails()
  location: class String
1 error

Comment: We don't know what the `s` array is, or how you're setting it up.  We need more code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rMGr1nyr

Comment: Side note: In Java, there is a widely accepted coding convention that class names should start with an uppercase letter. If a name consists of more than one word, the usual style would be camel case (first letter of each word upper case). So in your example the class name would be e.g. `Elements`, method names (which start with a  lower case letter) e.g. `showDetails()`

Comment: Well, that's your problem.  `s` is an array of `String`, so `s[i]` is a `String`, and `String` doesn't have a `showdetails` method.  If you thought the code would figure out that you wanted the variable with that name--forget it, code doesn't read minds.  If you're looking for a way to take that `String` and find the variable with the same name--forget it, you don't want to do that in Java.  Find a tutorial on `Maps` and learn about them.  It's one of the most important things you will need to learn anyway, so just do it.

Comment: Some reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html your key is the element symbol (for example `H`), your value is the `Element` instance (for example `Element hydrogen = new Element(1, "Hydrogen", 1.008);`), you fill the map, then you can do `theMap.get("H").showDetails();`

Answer (score 1):

In Java, a Map associates (or maps) one object (a key) to another (a value). There are different implementations of Maps in Java, but since you're new, just use the HashMap implementation. It's a good general purpose implementation when you don't have to access the HashMap in multiple threads.

A simple way in your case would be to write a function that creates the map, populates it with your element classes, and then returns the fully populated map. After that, you can perform a lookup based on the element's symbol.

e.g. (please note, I've put your class name in caps according to Java style (when in Rome!))

```
// add these lines to top of file
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

// example population function

public Map<String, Element> getElements() {
    Map<String, Element> elements = new HashMap<>();
    elements.put("H", new Element(1, "Hydrogen", 1.008));
    // etc...
    return elements;
}

// Getting your map of data and using it.

Map<String, Element> elements = getElements();
System.out.println(elements.get("H"));
```

Another thing to keep in mind when you're declaring a Map. You should tell Java what types the key and value are supposed to be. In this code we're associating the element symbol (a string) with your element class, so we need to put that in angle braces. e.g.

```
Map<String, Element> elements;
```

Notice that the return type of the function matches the type of the variable `elements`.

There are two other things that are different about this example than the code in your question that you should take note of.

First, it uses a constructor to populate the element. A constructor is a like an initializer function with the same name as your class, and it can be used in conjunction with the `new` operator.

Second, it defines a `toString()` method. A `toString()` method returns a string representation of an object in Java. This is preferable to simply printing from within the class because it can be used in many more situations than printing from a method.

Here's the code.

```
public class Element {
    private int atomicNumber;
    private String name;
    private double weight;

    public Element (int a, String n, double w) {
        atomicNumber = a;
        name = n;
        weight = w;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Atomic number = " + atomicNumber + ", " +
            "Name = " + name + "," +  
            "Weight = " + weight;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide me the basic syntax of declaring hashmap? because in this working example i don't quite get how can i declare and use it

Comment: It would be like this: `Map<String, Element> elements = new HashMap<>();`, which is the first line of the `getElements()` function above.